# Absolute vs. relative paths

Tags: php, relative-path, absolute-path

If I use absolute paths, I can't move the whole directory to a new location.
If I use relative paths, I can't move individual files to new locations.

What's the solution here? Do you set up a config file that holds the root path and go from there? Or do you have a rule like: Never move files around?

I've seen in some projects that people use dirname(**FILE**). What is the point of that, I mean, why not simply leave it out since the dirname is relative anyway (depending on where the file sits)?

Comment: The use of `dirname(__FILE__)` or `__DIR__` is that even when the file is included it will still return the directory of the current script. If you have a file that includes dir/script.php the default include path in script.php will be the root and not dir/.

Comment: @Frank Vilea: *Do you set up a config file that holds the root path and go from there?* **yes**

Comment: I am pretty bad at this myself, but I guess the idea is to mix those two up. Bu adding a absolute-path to the main-script and relative-paths to the file included and used in the script. of course, you can never move any of the files using a relative path without changing something in the relative-path declaration.

Comment: I'm with @aSeptik here, having a setting in your config file holding the root path is often the best solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you should use a config file that will be included in each file first line, for example your app look like this

root / App / Plugins

inside your root dir : `app-config.php`

```
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

now, suppose you have to include a plugin file, so

inside your Plugin dir : `my-plugin.php`

```
require_once '../../app-config.php';
```

now everything below this line can use `ABSPATH`

example do you want to load an image

```
<img src='".ABSPATH."Public/images/demo.png' alt=''/>
```

now, the thing is more simple if your app is designed to automatically load some files like

```
plugin-widget-1.php
```

so that everything inside this file or any other file loaded by the `my-plugin.php` file can use the `ABSPATH` without include each time the  `app-config.php` file.

with this in mind you can have all the short-hand you want into the `app-config.php` example

```
define('UPLOAD_PATH', ABSPATH. 'Public/uploads/');
define('IMAGES_PATH', ABSPATH. 'Public/images/');
define('HELPERS_PATH', ABSPATH. 'App/helpers/');
...
```

so, now that you have all defined, if you need to move a file, let's say one folder forward example:

root / App / Plugins / Utils

just inlucde `require_once '../../../app-config.php';`

obviously i suppose that you are not changing paths each time =) anyway if you need to do so is always more simple to change one file inclusion instead of hundreds.

hope this make sense to you =)

Answer (score 2):

> I've seen in some projects that people use dirname(FILE). What is the point of that, I mean, why not simply leave it out since the dirname is relative anyway (depending on where the file sits)?

It's relative to the include path, anyway. The `dirname( __FILE__ )` (or just `__DIR__` in PHP >= 5.3) is there so you can run the file from every location. In case you're using relative paths, the value "." may change. See:

berry@berry-pc:~% **cat so.php**

```
<?php
var_dump( realpath( '.' ) );
var_dump( realpath( __DIR__ ) );
```

berry@berry-pc:~% **php so.php**

```
string(11) "/home/berry"
string(11) "/home/berry"
```

berry@berry-pc:~% **cd foo**

berry@berry-pc:~/foo% **php ../so.php**

```
string(15) "/home/berry/foo"
string(11) "/home/berry"
```

So, it is relative, but it's relative to the current working directory, not to the directory the file is located in. That's why you'll want to use `__DIR__` for this. And by the way; yes, I don't move files around an awful lot. If I do though, I'll have to update every call to that file, although I don't require or include an awful lot anymore, since I'm using an [Autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

As for the other files I'm referring to (such as template files), I set the path manually, but *once*. I then refer to `$path . '/filename.php';`, so it's easier to change later.

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed post. Now it makes sense. Also the autoload feature seems very neat.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your usage, define a constant to hold application path is one of the common practice

Don't use variable as it might get override somewhere in your application and can break your application

Is even better to combine with symlink (symbolic to create branches)

```
application dirs
===============================
/home/latest         -> symlink
/home/testing        -> symlink
/home/20111202000000 -> latest development version
/home/20111201000000 -> yesterday stable release
```

So, you can symbolic link
/home/testing -> /home/20111202000000 while keeping the stable version,
/home/latest -> /home/20111201000000

With this, you don't have to risk to break your production site while doing some testing/development, and, you can easily shift your development directory

Answer (score 1):

I always use absolute paths, but I also start any custom PHP project with a bootstrap file where I define the most commonly used paths as constants, based on values extracted from `$_SERVER`.

This is how I define my root paths :

```
define("LOCAL_PATH_ROOT", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
define("HTTP_PATH_ROOT", isset($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]) ? $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] : (isset($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]) ? $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] : '_UNKNOWN_'));
```

The path `LOCAL_PATH_ROOT` is the document root. The path `HTTP_PATH_ROOT` is the equivalent when accessing the same path via HTTP.

At that point, converting any local path to an HTTP path can be done with the following code :

```
str_replace(LOCAL_PATH_ROOT, RELATIVE_PATH_ROOT, $my_path)
```

If you want to ensure compatibility with Windows based servers, you'll need to replace the directory seperator with a URL seperator as well :

```
str_replace(LOCAL_PATH_ROOT, RELATIVE_PATH_ROOT, str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/', $my_path))
```

Here's the full bootstrap code that I'm using for the [PHP PowerTools boilerplate](https://github.com/PHPPowertools/Boilerplate) :

```
defined('LOCAL_PATH_BOOTSTRAP') || define("LOCAL_PATH_BOOTSTRAP", __DIR__);

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// DEFINE SEPERATOR ALIASES
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
define("URL_SEPARATOR", '/');
define("DS", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define("PS", PATH_SEPARATOR);
define("US", URL_SEPARATOR);

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// DEFINE ROOT PATHS
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
define("RELATIVE_PATH_ROOT", '');
define("LOCAL_PATH_ROOT", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
define("HTTP_PATH_ROOT",
        isset($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]) ?
        $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] : (
        isset($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]) ?
        $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] : '_UNKNOWN_'));

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// DEFINE RELATIVE PATHS
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
define("RELATIVE_PATH_BASE",
        str_replace(LOCAL_PATH_ROOT, RELATIVE_PATH_ROOT, getcwd()));
define("RELATIVE_PATH_APP", dirname(RELATIVE_PATH_BASE));
define("RELATIVE_PATH_LIBRARY", RELATIVE_PATH_APP . DS . 'vendor');
define("RELATIVE_PATH_HELPERS", RELATIVE_PATH_BASE);
define("RELATIVE_PATH_TEMPLATE", RELATIVE_PATH_BASE . DS . 'templates');
define("RELATIVE_PATH_CONFIG", RELATIVE_PATH_BASE . DS . 'config');
define("RELATIVE_PATH_PAGES", RELATIVE_PATH_BASE . DS . 'pages');
define("RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET", RELATIVE_PATH_BASE . DS . 'assets');
define("RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_IMG", RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET . DS . 'img');
define("RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_CSS", RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET . DS . 'css');
define("RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_JS", RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET . DS . 'js');

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// DEFINE LOCAL PATHS
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
define("LOCAL_PATH_BASE", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_BASE);
define("LOCAL_PATH_APP", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_APP);
define("LOCAL_PATH_LIBRARY", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_LIBRARY);
define("LOCAL_PATH_HELPERS", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_HELPERS);
define("LOCAL_PATH_TEMPLATE", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_TEMPLATE);
define("LOCAL_PATH_CONFIG", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_CONFIG);
define("LOCAL_PATH_PAGES", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_PAGES);
define("LOCAL_PATH_ASSET", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET);
define("LOCAL_PATH_ASSET_IMG", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_IMG);
define("LOCAL_PATH_ASSET_CSS", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_CSS);
define("LOCAL_PATH_ASSET_JS", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_JS);

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// DEFINE URL PATHS
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
if (US === DS) { // needed for compatibility with windows
    define("HTTP_PATH_BASE", HTTP_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_BASE);
    define("HTTP_PATH_APP", HTTP_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_APP);
    define("HTTP_PATH_LIBRARY", false);
    define("HTTP_PATH_HELPERS", false);
    define("HTTP_PATH_TEMPLATE", false);
    define("HTTP_PATH_CONFIG", false);
    define("HTTP_PATH_PAGES", false);
    define("HTTP_PATH_ASSET", HTTP_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET);
    define("HTTP_PATH_ASSET_IMG", HTTP_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_IMG);
    define("HTTP_PATH_ASSET_CSS", HTTP_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_CSS);
    define("HTTP_PATH_ASSET_JS", HTTP_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_JS);
} else {
    define("HTTP_PATH_BASE", HTTP_PATH_ROOT .
            str_replace(DS, US, RELATIVE_PATH_BASE));
    define("HTTP_PATH_APP", HTTP_PATH_ROOT .
            str_replace(DS, US, RELATIVE_PATH_APP));
    define("HTTP_PATH_LIBRARY", false);
    define("HTTP_PATH_HELPERS", false);
    define("HTTP_PATH_TEMPLATE", false);
    define("HTTP_PATH_CONFIG", false);
    define("HTTP_PATH_PAGES", false);
    define("HTTP_PATH_ASSET", HTTP_PATH_ROOT .
            str_replace(DS, US, RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET));
    define("HTTP_PATH_ASSET_IMG", HTTP_PATH_ROOT .
            str_replace(DS, US, RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_IMG));
    define("HTTP_PATH_ASSET_CSS", HTTP_PATH_ROOT .
            str_replace(DS, US, RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_CSS));
    define("HTTP_PATH_ASSET_JS", HTTP_PATH_ROOT .
            str_replace(DS, US, RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_JS));
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// DEFINE REQUEST PARAMETERS
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
define("REQUEST_QUERY",
        isset($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]) && $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] != '' ?
        $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] : false);
define("REQUEST_METHOD",
        isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]) ?
        strtoupper($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]) : false);
define("REQUEST_STATUS",
        isset($_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"]) ?
        $_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"] : false);
define("REQUEST_PROTOCOL",
        isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"]) ?
        substr($_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"], 0,
        strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"], '://') + 3) : 'http://');
define("REQUEST_PATH",
        isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) ?
        str_replace(RELATIVE_PATH_BASE, '',
        $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) : '_UNKNOWN_');
define("REQUEST_PATH_STRIP_QUERY",
        REQUEST_QUERY ?
        str_replace('?' . REQUEST_QUERY, '', REQUEST_PATH) : REQUEST_PATH);

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// DEFINE SITE PARAMETERS
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
define("PRODUCTION", false);
define("PAGE_PATH_DEFAULT", US . 'index');
define("PAGE_PATH",
        (REQUEST_PATH_STRIP_QUERY === US) ?
        PAGE_PATH_DEFAULT : REQUEST_PATH_STRIP_QUERY);
```

If you add the above code to your own project, outputting all user constants at this point (which can do with `get_defined_constants(true)` should give a result that looks somewhat like this :

```
array (
  'LOCAL_PATH_BOOTSTRAP' => '/var/www/libraries/backend/Data/examples',
  'URL_SEPARATOR' => '/',
  'DS' => '/',
  'PS' => ':',
  'US' => '/',
  'RELATIVE_PATH_ROOT' => '',
  'LOCAL_PATH_ROOT' => '/var/www',
  'HTTP_PATH_ROOT' => 'localhost:8888',
  'RELATIVE_PATH_BASE' => '/libraries/backend/Data/examples',
  'RELATIVE_PATH_APP' => '/libraries/backend/Data',
  'RELATIVE_PATH_LIBRARY' => '/libraries/backend/Data/vendor',
  'RELATIVE_PATH_HELPERS' => '/libraries/backend/Data/examples',
  'RELATIVE_PATH_TEMPLATE' => '/libraries/backend/Data/examples/templates',
  'RELATIVE_PATH_CONFIG' => '/libraries/backend/Data/examples/config',
  'RELATIVE_PATH_PAGES' => '/libraries/backend/Data/examples/pages',
  'RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET' => '/libraries/backend/Data/examples/assets',
  'RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_IMG' => '/libraries/backend/Data/examples/assets/img',
  'RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_CSS' => '/libraries/backend/Data/examples/assets/css',
  'RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_JS' => '/libraries/backend/Data/examples/assets/js',
  'LOCAL_PATH_BASE' => '/var/www/libraries/backend/Data/examples',
  'LOCAL_PATH_APP' => '/var/www/libraries/backend/Data',
  'LOCAL_PATH_LIBRARY' => '/var/www/libraries/backend/Data/vendor',
  'LOCAL_PATH_HELPERS' => '/var/www/libraries/backend/Data/examples',
  'LOCAL_PATH_TEMPLATE' => '/var/www/libraries/backend/Data/examples/templates',
  'LOCAL_PATH_CONFIG' => '/var/www/libraries/backend/Data/examples/config',
  'LOCAL_PATH_PAGES' => '/var/www/libraries/backend/Data/examples/pages',
  'LOCAL_PATH_ASSET' => '/var/www/libraries/backend/Data/examples/assets',
  'LOCAL_PATH_ASSET_IMG' => '/var/www/libraries/backend/Data/examples/assets/img',
  'LOCAL_PATH_ASSET_CSS' => '/var/www/libraries/backend/Data/examples/assets/css',
  'LOCAL_PATH_ASSET_JS' => '/var/www/libraries/backend/Data/examples/assets/js',
  'HTTP_PATH_BASE' => 'localhost:8888/libraries/backend/Data/examples',
  'HTTP_PATH_APP' => 'localhost:8888/libraries/backend/Data',
  'HTTP_PATH_LIBRARY' => false,
  'HTTP_PATH_HELPERS' => false,
  'HTTP_PATH_TEMPLATE' => false,
  'HTTP_PATH_CONFIG' => false,
  'HTTP_PATH_PAGES' => false,
  'HTTP_PATH_ASSET' => 'localhost:8888/libraries/backend/Data/examples/assets',
  'HTTP_PATH_ASSET_IMG' => 'localhost:8888/libraries/backend/Data/examples/assets/img',
  'HTTP_PATH_ASSET_CSS' => 'localhost:8888/libraries/backend/Data/examples/assets/css',
  'HTTP_PATH_ASSET_JS' => 'localhost:8888/libraries/backend/Data/examples/assets/js',
  'REQUEST_QUERY' => false,
  'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET',
  'REQUEST_STATUS' => false,
  'REQUEST_PROTOCOL' => 'http://',
  'REQUEST_PATH' => '/',
  'REQUEST_PATH_STRIP_QUERY' => '/',
  'PRODUCTION' => false,
  'PAGE_PATH_DEFAULT' => '/index',
  'PAGE_PATH' => '/index',
)
```

Comment: This is breathtakingly elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute paths are better from a performance point of view when using an opcode cache or lots of require/include statement (although its only noticeable when you start to include hundreds of files, as might happen when using a framework like Zend/Symfony/etc).

With a relative path the opcode cache and php must work out the files realpath each time before it can work out if it already knows about the file and if it needs to load it again. PHP internally maintains a hashmap of files to file locations which is very quick as long it doesn't have to do the above calculation each time.