# How to call one folder into logged in file but when i connect my file through index.php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, css

I'm working on a project for web application now my problem is I have login script which contain a views folder. Inside `view` folder I have three PHP files:

1. `logged-in.php`
2. `not_logged_in.php`
3. `register.php`

Apart my `view` folder I have one file `index.php` now have a look this picture [click here](http://postimg.org/image/6d1ufk5nn/).

Now when I run `index.php` file, it shows login main page if user is not logged in, otherwise will show up home page( which is `logged-in.php` inside view folder) if I run direct `logged-in.php` file directly then it will give an error so the whole process I must startup with `index.php`.

And here is code for `index.php`

```
<?php
// checking for minimum PHP version
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.7', '<')) {
    exit("Sorry, Simple PHP Login does not run on a PHP version smaller than 5.3.7 !");
} else if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0', '<')) {
    // if you are using PHP 5.3 or PHP 5.4 you have to include the password_api_compatibility_library.php
    // (this library adds the PHP 5.5 password hashing functions to older versions of PHP)
    require_once("libraries/password_compatibility_library.php");
}

// include the configs / constants for the database connection
require_once("config/db.php");

// load the login class
require_once("classes/Login.php");

// create a login object. when this object is created, it will do all login/logout stuff automatically
// so this single line handles the entire login process. in consequence, you can simply ...
$login = new Login();

// ... ask if we are logged in here:
if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {
    // the user is logged in. you can do whatever you want here.
    // for demonstration purposes, we simply show the "you are logged in" view.
    include("views/logged_in.php");

} else {
    // the user is not logged in. you can do whatever you want here.
    // for demonstration purposes, we simply show the "you are not logged in" view.
    include("views/not_logged_in.php");
}
```

Have a look at this [pic](http://postimg.org/image/rwol4c2tf/), so the problem is I want to call my `comment-folder` inside `logged-in.php` so I use `include('comment05/../.. .php');` inside my logged-in.php as you can see my pic.

But when I run this it shows the comment popup but when I click `comment` button it's giving error `404 file not found` that mean it's recognizing the correct path. So I want to ask, do I need to change something into my `index.php` file or not? Because I guess I need to change something in their like using using `include('comment05')` and etc.

So can you help me with `index.php` file, what should I do in that case when I call a folder into `logged-in.php` file because the whole process is depend into `index.php` file? I mean my website is startup firstly with `index.php`.

Comment: Check your file permissions to the comments folder.

Comment: Always use absolute paths in include() or require() functions.see example for absolute path http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356547/php-absolute-vs-relative-paths