# How to call function across projects in PHP

Tags: php, function

I have 2 projects that'll like to share functions. Function-A, in project-A, should be called by function-B, in project-B. Any quickest way to achieve it?

Example function-A

```
function upload($file, $path){
   $CFG->file    = $file;
   $CFG->path    = $path;
}
```

How do I call this function in function-B, project-B

```
function callUpload(  ){
   upload( "a.png", "application/path/file" );
}
```

Comment: What is Project-B? Where are the files located? Do you know PHP has classes?

Comment: Project-B, is the authentication app, while project-A is the main app for products. One  runs on XAMPP, while the other on MAMP. They are both PHP projects.

Comment: @Barmar, boss, why down-vote the question? Just want to know sir. Thanks.

Comment: Anyone can downvote, and it is unlikely somehow who took the time to edit your question also downvoted. At any rate, this question seems like something better suited for a tutorial site because it is not quite a specific coding question; this may be the reason for the downvotes. What research have you done? I'm sure there are plenty of tutorial and info sites that talk about how to share PHP functions.

Comment: @kehinde I didn't downvote, I just edited the question to fix the misspelling in the title.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks boss. Appreciate.

Answer (score -1):

Create a file that you include() at the top of each one.  This file would contain the function, and then can be used across script:

```
include('functions.php');
```

Or create a Class and use that in the same way.

functions.php

```
function upload($file, $path){
   $CFG->file    = $file;
   $CFG->path    = $path;
}
```

scriptA.php & scriptB.php

```
include('functions.php');
upload($file, $path);
```

For further reference, check this out: [How to call function of one php file from another php file and pass parameters to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104998/how-to-call-function-of-one-php-file-from-another-php-file-and-pass-parameters-t)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. i meant across 2 PHP projects. This is for directories within the same projects.

Comment: You could use a full qualified path for it if you are able to provide the full path, as ana example,`include('/var/projects/shared/functions.php')`

Comment: No problem, my answer on here will give you more information about relative and absolute paths: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52003582/accessing-a-stylesheet-from-a-php-file/52003658#52003658

Comment: Thanks sir. highly honored for this kindness.

Comment: Happy to help! If it works for you and my answer helped you, don't forget to mark it as correct =]

Comment: 5 years on but did this work for you?