# fopen() failed to open stream : no such file or directory

Tags: php

I have `mypage.php` where I try to `fopen` a file, but I get:

`Warning: fopen(/json/subcat/list.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

This is how I try to open file: `$json = fopen("/json/subcat/list.json", "r");`
This is the tree of project:

[image]

P.S.: I use `xampp` and `root` is `.../htdocs/projectName/` and 
`list.json` contains `{"list": ["a", "b"]}`, if matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a full path using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

```
$json = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/json/subcat/list.json", "r");
```

This will give you the file path to your document root, and then will append the rest of the path onto it.

Or you relative paths, which is:

```
$json = fopen("json/subcat/list.json", "r");
```

Without the first /

Check out this link for more information about relative and absolute paths: [Absolute vs. relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356547/absolute-vs-relative-paths)

Comment: First time I tried `json/subcat/list.json` but got that error, after that I put `/json/subcat/list.json` hoping it will work.

Comment: That don't give me the right path. `C:/xampp/htdocs/json/subcat/list.json` is missing the name of project after `htdocs`. It should be `C:/xampp/htdocs/projname/json/subcat/list.json`

Comment: Add the project name in there then?

Comment: `$json = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/projectName/json/subcat/list.json", "r");`

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` gives you the path to your webroot... so that additional folder is your problem... `$json = fopen("/projectName/json/subcat/list.json", "r");` will probably work

Comment: So your questions image seems a bit wrong... you're root isn't the projectname... it's C:/xampp/htdocs

Comment: I added it, but still error. I copy pasted `C:/xampp/htdocs/projname/json/subcat` into explorer and it works. I don't get why php get me error.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of C:/xampp/htdocs in explorer so I can see filepaths? Perhaps another folder is required

Comment: If still not working, though path is now correct, then could be permissions.  You may need to go to htdocs, and propagate the permissions down to child directories

Comment: Also, I presume you can actually access pages via the Broswers that are in htdocs?  Can you add a new php file, called phpinfo.php... in there add <?php phpinfo(); ?> and then access that page via your broswers?

Comment: Just try to dump the ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) may be the result will help you

Comment: There was a space into the name of file `list .json`.

Answer (score 1):

You are providing a full-path:

```
$json = fopen("/json/subcat/list.json", "r");
```

and you should be providing a relative path:

```
$json = fopen("json/subcat/list.json", "r");
```

Your full path is something like `/var/www/htdocs/projectName/json/subcat/list.json`.

Comment: First time I tried `json/subcat/list.json` but got that error, after that I put `/json/subcat/list.json` hoping it will work.

Comment: Does your webserver user have permission?

Comment: I don't know about that... I'm using xampp. I need that at xampp?

Comment: Could you post the entire code, also, make sure the folders are exactly named this way (be wary for spaces before or after the folder name).

Comment: There was a space into the name of file `list .json`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//your project folder:
$projectFolde = "my_project_folder";

$json = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/json/subcat/list.json", "r");
```

Comment: Got there just after me :p

Comment: you deserve the first place :D